# R code chunk printing extra line in Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I'm creating a data analysis report using Markdown, knitr.

When I run a code chunk containing a table,

```
addmargins(table(x$gender, exclude=NULL))
```

This is what I get:

```
## 
## Female   Male   <NA>    Sum 
##     49     53      0    102
```

This is what I want:

```
## Female   Male   <NA>    Sum 
##     49     53      0    102
```

Markdown naturally outputs a lot of white space, and I'm trying to provide as condensed an output as possible since these reports need to be printed. These extra lines add up to be a lot of extra pages.

As far as I've seen, this seems to happen only with tables, and not with other code. It seems that `table()` is causing the problem by inserting the extra line above the table. Any way to disable this quirk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `table()` is printing a blank line for your dimension names. If you specify `dnn=NULL`, it should go away.

```
addmargins(table(x$gender, exclude=NULL, dnn=NULL))
```

Comment: @tammypham No problem, please consider marking the answer as correct.

Comment: Oops, I thought I had done that earlier. Just did. Thanks again!